# Put All Data to Array From Firebase Storage in Asynchronous Function React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, promise, firebase-storage

i am trying to fetch all images in firebase storage. So far it works. But the problem is how to put ALL data inside array in asynchronous function and not just one then pass it into state?

My Code :

```
   async componentDidMount(){
        auth().signInAnonymously();

        var arr = [];
        var storageRef = storage().ref("/madu_mubarak/");
        await storageRef.listAll().then((result)=> {
            result.items.forEach((imageItem) =>{
              this.displayItem(imageItem)
            });
          }).catch(function(error) {
            console.warn("error "+error);
          });


    }

    async displayItem(imageItem){
        var arr = [];
        imageItem.getDownloadURL().
            then((url) => {
          console.warn("ur "+url)
          arr.push(url);
          this.setState({
            isLoad: false,
            urlImage: arr
          })
        }).catch((error) =>{
          console.warn("error "+error);
        });


        // return await Promise.all(arr);
    }
```

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: Take a look at Promise.all([...]). You can pass it an array of promises and it resolves only when all promises in the array resolves

Comment: @TomSlutsky i already look at Promise.all. But i am still new at that so i dont understand how to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main gist is this

```js
async componentDidMount(){
        auth().signInAnonymously();


        var storageRef = storage().ref("/madu_mubarak/");
        await storageRef.listAll().then((result)=> {
           let promises = result.items.map((imageItem) =>{
              return imageItem.getDownloadURL()
            });
            Promise.all(promises).then(urls => this.setState({images: urls})

    }
```

You want to create an array of the promises returned from getDownloadUrl and the wait for all of them to resolve with Primise.all
you can then assign the result to the state